# Finding a pair of commutative stochastic $3 \times 3$ matrices

Tags: matrices, stochastic-matrices

Could you please give me an example of a pair $\left(A,B\right)$ of commutative stochastic $3 \times 3$ matrices with real entries given $A \neq B$ and excluding the identity matrix, symmetric matrices and doubly stochastic matrices?

Comment: What is the motivation for this question?

Comment: $B=A^2$ if $A$ not idempotent.

Answer (score 1):

We can show that powers of any square matrix $A^n$ will commute with $A$ itself, which follows immediately from the fact that matrix multiplication is associative.

So long as you pick some arbitrary stochastic matrix A which is not the identity matrix, symmetric matrix, and doubly stochastic, and pick some B where $B = A^n$ and $A^n \neq A$ you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I add a motivation to my question: I'm working on inhomogeneous Markov chains and I'm trying to find an example of an inhomogeneous Markov chain with commuting (possibly diagonalizable) transition matrices. Your answer, while correct and not excluded by the restrictions in my question, still brings me back to an homougeneous Markov chain.

Answer (score 1):

What it we take $B$ a convex combination of powers of $A$?  In generic cases, if two matrices commute $A$, $B$ commute one $B$ will be a polynomial in the other $A$ ( if the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct).

$\bf{Added:}$ Here is a stochastic matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $1$, $\frac{1}{6}$, $\frac{1}{6}$

$$A=\left( \begin{matrix} \frac{11}{18} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{18} \\ \frac{4}{9} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{18} \\ \frac{4}{9} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{9} \end{matrix} \right)$$

$\bf{Added:}$ Some calculations show that the $3\times 3$ stochastic matrices with eigenvalues $1$, $\lambda$, $\lambda$ are of the form
$$A=\left( \begin{matrix} a & b & 1-a-b \\ p & q & 1-p-q \\ u & v & w=1-v-w\end{matrix} \right)$$

where $$u = p+ \frac{(t-1)^2}{4} (a+b-p-q)\\
v = b-\frac{(t+1)^2}{4}(a+b-p-q)\\
w = (1-b-p) + t\,(a+b-p-q)$$

Positivity of entrier is also required. To check the result, see [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7Ba%2Cb%2C1-a-b%7D%2C%7Bp%2Cq%2C1-p-q%7D%2C%20%7Bu%2Cv%2C%20w%7D%7D%2F.%20%7Bu-%3Ep%2B%20%28t-1%29%5E2%2F4%20%28a%2Bb-p-q%29%2C%20v-%3Eb-%28t%2B1%29%5E2%2F4%20%28a%2Bb-p-q%29%2C%20w-%3E1-b-p%2Bt%28a%2Bb-p-q%29%7D). This follows from the [factorization](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5BDiscriminant%5BCharacteristicPolynomial%5B%7B%7Ba%2Cb%2C1-a-b%7D%2C%20%7Bp%2Cq%2C1-p-q%7D%2C%7Bu%2Cv%2C1-u-v%7D%7D%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D%20%5D) of the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial of a stochastic $3\times 3$ matrix

$$\Delta= (1 - a - b p - q + a q + u + b u - q u + v - a v + p v)^2\\ \cdot (a^2 + 4 b p - 2 a q + q^2 - 2 a u - 4 b u + 2 q u + u^2 + 2 a v - 4 p v - 2 q v + 2 u v + v^2)$$

The first factor in the square is $\ge 0$ for stochastic matrices ( it being $0$ is  the condition that the matrix has two eigenvalues $1$).

The second factor equals:
$$(a-q-u+v)^2 + (b+p-u-v)^2 - (b-p+u-v)^2$$

It is the solutions to this expression being $0$ tnat are parametrized by the above (we may be missing some solutions corresponding to $t=\infty$).

Comment: Fine, but could you give me any reference for your statement about generic cases?

Comment: Generically, a matrix has distinct eigenvalues ( since this is true for a polynomial). Now, it $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, then $SAS^{-1} = D$, diagonal with distinct entries. The matrices commuting with $D$ are all diagonal, so polynomial in $D$, and the same will happen for matrices commuting with $A$.